# Chrome extension: access one of many values with the same key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Google Chrome extension and I am using the chrome.storage API.

I am storing the url of a page using:

```
    chrome.storage.local.set({'url': document.URL});
```

But this function is called multiple times, and so in the storage there are multiple different URL's with the same 'url' key.

To get the value I use:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('url', function (urlResult) {
url = urlResult.url;
document.getElementById("urlInfo").innerHTML = url;
});
```

But this will return only the last of the values stored in the key.
So for example, if I visit https://stackoverflow.com/ first and https://github.com/ second, my code will only return the github address. Is it possible to access the stackoverflow value while having multiple values for the same key?

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your tip @SLaks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SLaks mentioned, you could save urls in an array.

Set:

```
chrome.storage.local.get({urls: []}, function (result) {
    var urls = result.urls;
    urls.push(document.URL);
    chrome.storage.local.set({ urls: urls });
});
```

Get:

```
chrome.storage.local.get({urls: []}, function (result) {
    var urls = result.urls;
    var url1 = urls.find((url) => url === 'https://www.stackoverflow.com');
    var url2 = urls.find((url) => url === 'https://www.github.com');
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! I do have one more question though. I checked my local storage file and it seems that every time a new element is added to the array, it retains the previous array and appends the new array into the same file. So after vising stackoverflow.com and github.com my file has ["stackoverflow"], ["stackoverflow", "github"]. I tried `chrome.storage.local.remove({ urls: urls });` before doing "set", but doing that seems to make the next "set" not work. Any suggestions? :(

Comment: @hollaholl, what's "local storage file"? And how do you add the element to the array?

Comment: By 'local storage file' I mean where the information is stored. It's in `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\eilllankfpchokjofpgnhjbfppmhjckh`. The filename is `000003.txt`. The file looks a bit messy but it clearly keeps the previous array intact and appends the new one. I add elements to the array in exactly the way you've shown me using push:     `chrome.storage.local.get({urls: []}, function (result) {
        var urls = result.urls;
        urls.push(document.URL);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ urls: urls });
    }); `

Comment: @hollaholl, sorry but I even didn't know that the storage process would be saved into a file... If possible, could you please post another question? Maybe someone else who has experience with this scenario would help.